# Colouring a listview custom item element basing on value

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple (?) problem that I can't seem able to fix.

I have to populate a listview with two columns - two string arrays.
I managed to do so, after searching a lot (see [here](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/android-listview-with-multiple-string-arrays-using-simple-adapter/)).

Now, what I need to do is to colour the background of the second item red, purple or blue depending on its value.

Is it possible?

I know that many things can be done with custom listviews, even assigning different images based on a particular value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your listadapter (for example see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example) override getView() and when setting the value of the second textview set its background color. e.g.:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
     TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
     textView.setText(values[position]);

     String s = values[position];
     if (s.startsWith("red")) {
        //BACKGROUND COLOR CHANGE
         textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_red));**
     } 

   return rowView;
```

}